# How to Host an R Markdown Document with Shiny enabled internally (over LAN)

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I need to share some Shiny applications with coworkers over the same network. Currently there is a way to do this (given you have the right firewall permissions within your enterprise/device).

With a standard shiny app you can use (has app.R file)

```
options(shiny.host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
options(shiny.port = 1234)

shiny::runApp("app.r")
```

Others can then access the application by typing my ip:port into their web browser.

From the rmarkdown documentation there appears to be a similar solution using

```
rmarkdown::run("some_rmarkdown_file.rmd",shiny_args=list(host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",port=1234))
```

This hosts the app, however if another user tries to access the shiny enable document from my ip:port none of the data populates into the various widgets. All that the user sees is a blank shell of the rmarkdown document with no data.

I believe these options are aimed at solving this problem, but none of them have worked

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_prerendered.html#overview

Comment: `rmarkdown::run("test.rmd", shiny_args=list(host="0.0.0.0", port=1234))` works fine for me from different local PCs.